# Custom options in nutch crawl script not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I was trying to give custom options in ***bin/crawl*** script and encountered an issue. I gave a custom config in nutch to ignore external outlinks in my crawl command like :-

***bin/crawl -i -D elastic.index=test -D db.ignore.external.links=true urls/ CrawlTest/ 3***

But this is not working. Then I set this property in nutch-site.xml then it is working.

Then I tried to set a custom config to index data to a specific elastic index other than what is given in nutch-site.xml as java option in bin/crawl. To my surprise it is working.
The command I've used :-

***bin/crawl -i -D elastic.index=test urls/ CrawlTest/ 3***

So I would like to know why my first command didn't work ?Am I missing anything. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From further study I got the answer myselves. First command didn't work because hadoop doesn't detect it as an argument. It should be read from nutch config itselves.